# how to make an html visible/unvisible when the browser is of a specific viewport?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to make an html element be visible when the browser is of a small viewport and to make it invisible when it is of a large viewport. I have tried positioning it but it doesn't properly work. What should i do?

Comment: Have you googled your problem? There are a lot of solutions for your answer. [This](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) can help you.

Comment: @media is a method in css to perform an action depending on the size of the window. inside the method you can hide your html element there

Answer (score 1):

You can use a media query:
*(Note: the StackOverflow snippet only works when viewed in full page)*

```css
@media (min-width: 768px){
  .hiddenLarge { display: none; }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Always visible</label><br/>
  <label class="hiddenLarge">Only visible on small screens</label>
 <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with media query:
ex.

```
@media (min-width : 1281px) and (max-width: 1366px){
 .codeToHideClass {
    display:none;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this:

```
var w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
var h = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
$('#output').text(w + ',' + h);
if (h < 700) {
    $('#sizedependend').hide();
}
```

try it on http://jsfiddle.net/82fhmqkg/ by resizing the output window